# Getting error "msg 8156" on doing a merge with a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am doing a merge with a number of left joins and they are using the same key I am using with my on statement, and I am getting from SQL Server:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_CommonLoanData, Line 41
>   The column 'LNKEY' was specified multiple times for 'l'.
>   my the way the I have tested the select statement and it works and retrieves all of the data.
>   Code

```
   /*********************************************************************************
Author: Herb Williams 
Date: Oct 08 2014 
Purpose: This stored procedure builds the CommonLoanData table in CTS from the replicated 
         Empower tables in CTS. It check the  Using Merge below is the process. 
         1. Update if there is a loan number

         2. Inserted if there is not a loan number 

*********************************************************************************/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CommonLoanData]

---------------------------------------
-- I N S E R T  
---------------------------------------

AS
MERGE CommonLoanData AS cl
USING (Select   l.LNKEY as mainKey, 
                l.STOREDON,  
                f.NEWFHACASEDATE,
                m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
                d.DISBDATE, 
                w.COLLATERALORIGRECVD,
                w.HEDGEDATE,
                l.LNKEY,
                b.BORR_LAST, 
                b.BORR_FIRST,
                p.PROPWILLBE,
                lp.LPLANDESC,
                pf.REF_PURP,
                m.AMORTTYPE,
                lp.NUMPMTS,
                m.INTRATE,
                m.LOANAMT,
                m.LTV,
                r.HOUSING_RATIO,
                dd.EW_RETAXES,
                dd.EW_HAZINS,
                dd.EW_FLOODINS,
                a.AUSRESULT,
                t.REPCREDSCORE,
                s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN,
                m.PRC_BASE_PTS,`enter 
                ma.POINTS_ADJ,
                m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
                w.ALL_IN_PRICE,
                pa.ADJ_DESC,
                pa.POINTS_ADJ,
                m.LOCKINDATE,
                m.LOCKINEXPIRES,
                c.U_AGENT_WAREHOUSE,
                i.AGENT_COMPANY,
                repairs.amt,
                s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN,
                r.DEBT_RATIO,
                m.CLTV,
                l.STOREDON


                from [EMPOWER].[LN_DBLOCKS] AS l
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_MTGTERMS]       AS m  on  (m.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_MANUAL_PRC_ADJ] AS ma on  (ma.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_CODES]          AS cd on  (cd.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_DISBURSEMENTS]  AS d  on  (d.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_DEEDDATA]       AS dd on  (dd.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_BORRINFO]       AS b  on  (b.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_PLANDAT]        AS lp on  (lp.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_FHAVACLC]       AS f  on  (f.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_RATIOS]         AS r  on  (r.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_PROPINFO]       AS p  on  (p.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_PRICADJ]        AS pa on  (pa.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_PROPREFI]       AS pf on  (pf.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_SECTION35]      AS s3 on  (s3.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_AUS_RESULTS]    AS a  on  (a.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_CONTACTS]       AS c  on  (c.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_INVESTORS]      AS i  on  (i.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[LN_TRANSUMM]       AS t  on  (t.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    left join [EMPOWER].[U_LN_WEB_BUILDER]  AS w  on  (w.LNKEY = l.LNKEY)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT LNKEY, sum(ITEMCOST) amt FROM EMPOWER.LN_REPAIRFUNDS GROUP BY LNKEY) repairs on repairs.LNKEY = m.LNKEY)

        AS l
        ON (CommonLoanDataId = mainKey )
        and (l.STOREDON >  cl.LastUpdated)
---------------------------------------
-- M E R G E D
---------------------------------------

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE 
    SET  cl.BranchMarginAdj               = m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
         cl.ApplicationDate               = m.APP_DATE,
         cl.FHACaseFileDate               = f.NEWFHACASEDATE,
         cl.FundedDate                    = d.DISBDATE,
         cl.CollateralReceivedDate        = w.COLLATERALORIGRECVD,
         cl.HedgedDate                    = w.HEDGEDATE,
         cl.LoanNumber              = l.LNKEY,
         cl.BorrowerLastName        = b.BORR_LAST, 
         cl.BorrowerFirstName       = b.BORR_FIRST,
         cl.Occupancy               = p.PROPWILLBE,
         cl.PropertyState           = p.PROP_STATE,
         cl.PropertyType            = null,
         cl.Program                 = lp.LPLANDESC,
         cl.DocType                 = null,
         cl.LoanType                = null,
         cl.LoanPurpose             = null,
         cl.RefiPurpose             = pf.REF_PURP,
         cl.LienPosition            = null,
         cl.FinanceMethod           = m.AMORTTYPE,
         cl.Term                    = lp.NUMPMTS,
         cl.NoteRate                = m.INTRATE,
         cl.LoanAmount              = m.LOANAMT,
         cl.Ltv                     = m.LTV,
         cl.Hsg                     = r.HOUSING_RATIO,
         cl.WaivedImpounds          = case when dd.EW_RETAXES = 1 or dd.EW_HAZINS = 1 or dd.EW_FLOODINS = 1 then 1 end,
         cl.AUSType                 = null,
         cl.AUSDecision             = a.AUSRESULT,
         cl.LoanFico                = t.REPCREDSCORE,
         cl.MIType                  = null,
         cl.HPMLFlag                = s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN,
         cl.SecondaryNotesCPExceptionNotes =null,
         cl.BondStylePrice          = m.PRC_BASE_PTS,
         cl.ProgramPriceAdjTotal    = ma.POINTS_ADJ,
         cl.AdjustedBasePrice       = m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
         cl.AllInPrice              = w.ALL_IN_PRICE,
         cl.LLPANameItemized        = pa.ADJ_DESC,
         cl.LLPAAmountItemized      = pa.POINTS_ADJ,
         cl.LockDate                = m.LOCKINDATE,
         cl.LockExpiration          = m.LOCKINEXPIRES,
         cl.LockCanceled            = null,
         cl.CondoType               = null,
         cl.AUSRiskDecision         = null,
         cl.WarehouseLine           = c.U_AGENT_WAREHOUSE,
         cl.Investor                = i.AGENT_COMPANY,
         cl.ExclusionIndicator      = case when repairs.amt > 0 or mcc > 0 or s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN > 0 then 1 else 0 end,
         cl.Dti                     = r.DEBT_RATIO,
         cl.Cltv                    = m.CLTV,
         cl.[Source]                = null,
         cl.LastUpdated             = l.STOREDON,
         cl.WireSentDate            = null, 
         cl.WireReturningDate       = null,
         cl.ShippedToInvestorDate   = null,
         cl.InvestorPriceLockDate   = null,
         cl.InvestorPriceLockExpiration = null,
         cl.FirstInvestorPaymentDate = null,
         cl.PAReceivedDate           = null


WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT VALUES (
         m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
         m.APP_DATE,
         f.NEWFHACASEDATE,
         d.DISBDATE,
         w.COLLATERALORIGRECVD,
         w.HEDGEDATE,
         l.LNKEY,
         b.BORR_LAST, 
         b.BORR_FIRST,
         p.PROPWILLBE,
         p.PROP_STATE,
         null,
         lp.LPLANDESC,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         pf.REF_PURP,
         null,
         m.AMORTTYPE,
         lp.NUMPMTS,
         m.INTRATE,
         m.LOANAMT,
         m.LTV,
         r.HOUSING_RATIO,
         case when dd.EW_RETAXES = 1 or dd.EW_HAZINS = 1 or dd.EW_FLOODINS = 1 then 1 end,
         null,
         a.AUSRESULT,
         t.REPCREDSCORE,
         null,
         s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN,
         null,
         m.PRC_BASE_PTS,
         ma.POINTS_ADJ,
         m.ADJUSTED_BASE_RATE,
         w.ALL_IN_PRICE,
         pa.ADJ_DESC,
         pa.POINTS_ADJ,
         m.LOCKINDATE,
         m.LOCKINEXPIRES,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         c.U_AGENT_WAREHOUSE,
         i.AGENT_COMPANY,
         case when repairs.amt > 0 or mcc > 0 or s3.HIGH_PRICED_LOAN > 0 then 1 else 0 end,
         r.DEBT_RATIO,
         m.CLTV,
         null,
         l.STOREDON,
         null, 
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null,
         null);

SELECT  resource_type, request_mode, resource_description
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks

SELECT * FROM cl
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns of the derived table `l`instead of using `*`. it currently has about 15 columns called `LNKEY`.

With the updated SQL you now have two definitions of StoredOn

Comment: I removed the * and defined all of the elements for the merge I am still getting the msg 8156 on the merge:

Comment: the error is pointing to the this statement because I am using l.LNKEY multiple times "ON (CommonLoanDataId = l.LNKEY )and (l.STOREDON >  cl.LastUpdated)"

Comment: @HerbWilliams Write out the new SQL you are using.

Comment: @HerbWilliams I assume the `enter in the sql is just a typo. Apart from that you still have two definitions of StoredOn.